# is there anyway in fortran90 to read data at specied byte

Tags: file-io, binary, fortran, fortran90

I have encountered a problem that demands reading at data at specified byte from a binary input file,like reading at location 40000 bytes off the start of the file.I intend to use direct access to file.But that requires each segment be divided in the same size which specified in the argument `recl`.Can anybody provides a feasible solution.Some programming language like c provide function that can jump to the specified bytes.

Answer (score 3):

The Fortran 2003 standard introduced unformatted stream access, to pretty much do exactly this.  Once the file has been opened appropriately you can just use a POS specifier in the relevant write statement.  Support for this Fortran 2003 feature is reasonably widespread amongst the Fortran compilers that are actively supported.  The compiler needs to use a file storage unit of a byte, but all compilers that I am aware of do this (this is also what the standard recommends).

Otherwise, the closest standard Fortran 90 approach is to use unformatted direct access with a record length that is some reasonable common factor of the desired position and size of the elements of data to be read.  For instance - if you were reading eight byte real numbers from the file, then a record length of eight might work - you would start reading at record number 5000.  This requires both that the file storage unit of the Fortran processor be a byte (common, perhaps with compile options) and that no record delimiters or similar exists in the file for unformatted direct access (mostly the case, again perhaps with compile options).

Comment: could u show some segment of Fortran 2003 standard implementation?